# cakephp2 override Form input action

Tags: cakephp-2.x, formhelper, custom-tags

default cakephp `echo $this->Form->input('name');`

returns something like this

```
<div>
    <label for="mdl.name">name</label>
    <input type="text" id="mdl.name" name="mdl.name" />
</div>
```

but I want different let's say I want the the following

```
<div class="form-group more classes">
  <h3>name</h3>
  <div>
     <span class="extra span"></span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mdl.name">
     <span class="extra span"></span>
  </div>
  <label for="mdl.name">name</label>
  <span class="another span"></span>
</div>
```

I saw /lib/cake/view/Helper/FormHelper.php copied to app/view/Helper
but have not seen any `div`, `label` or `input` tags

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
'before' => '--before--',
'after' => '--after--',
'between' => '--between---'
));
```

Which will output:

```
<div class="input">
--before--
<label for="UserField">Field</label>
--between---
<input name="data[User][field]" type="text" value="" id="UserField" />
--after--
</div>
```

Reference: [CakePHP 2.x FormHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Comment: i need label after input, I know we can do it by passing so many `parameters` to `input()`, but I wanted to do it without passing any parameters, wanted to make above html using just `$this->Form->input('field',array(nothing));`